# Metals extension download failed

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, java-home, scala-metals

I'm trying to install metals for VS Code, it worked fine for me in the past.
However now when trying, I get thee following error message:
`Failed to download Metals, make sure you have an internet connection, the Metals version '0.11.6' is correct and the Java Home 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14' is valid. You can configure the Metals version and Java Home in the settings.See https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode/#http-proxy for instructions if you are using an HTTP proxy.`
I've checked, and the provided path is correct for the jdk.
So I have no clue why this error message keeps coming up.

Comment: Maybe it's internet connection issue, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issues, which turned out to be caused by the JRE version.
Try updating JRE/JDK to the latest version and adjusting the `JAVA_HOME` path.

After I performed these steps, Metals plugin started to work correctly.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing and somehow got it to work after hours of trial and error